# Configure mail client for Adobe Acrobat plugin 9.4.0

Tags: pdf

Adobe Acrobat plugin 9.4.0 has File | Attach to Email ..., but selecting it yields the following:

> The SendMail doesn't know how to talk
>   to your default mail client.  Please
>   select a different mail application to
>   use.

How does the user select which mail application for SendMail to use, and which mail applications does SendMail know how to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it looks to see which is your default mail app.  I also think that it will pretty much only work with Mail.app.  If you go into Mail.app, check which is the default email app (and re-set it, if required) on the Preferences -> General screen.  I bet setting it to Mail will fix your problem.

Comment: That was it!  My default email had been set to a web-mail's notifier.  Changing it to Mail made Acrobat happy.